# Extracting Specific Value out of XML

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I have a very complicated xml

and I need the single value from

```
selectSingleNode(@"/TimeInTransitResponse/TransitResponse/ServiceSummary/EstimatedArrival/BusinessTransitDays").InnerText)
```

but there are about 7 entries with this location so it only returns the first one i need the last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SelectNodes` instead:

```
Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = root.SelectNodes(@"/TimeInTransitResponse/TransitResponse/ServiceSummary/EstimatedArrival/BusinessTransitDays")
Dim lastNode As XmlNode = nodeList.Item(nodeList.Count - 1)
Dim lastNodeValue As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(lastNode.InnerText)
```

Then take the last node in the list.

Comment: how can i make sure its always the last node the node i need will ALWAYS be in the response and will always be last but i can never known if i will recieve 1,2,3,4,5,6, or 7 entries.

Comment: The nodeList will have a `Count`, just use `count - 1`. I will update my answer.

Comment: and how can i convert the last node to a decimal?

Comment: @MeghanGibbs, This is clearly another question that has been asked many times. Please consider searching for answer first. Also don't forget to vote on answers/accept one that you find useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use index and inside index you can put last() function - something like this:

```
"/TimeInTransitResponse/TransitResponse/ServiceSummary/EstimatedArrival/BusinessTransitDays[last()]"
```

See [last](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256083.aspx) XPath function in MSDN.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it simply did not work with a vs error "Error 1 The name 'Last' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Fixed XPath and aded link to MSDN (slighgly easier to read than original W3C one - http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/ )

Comment: Not sure why you got the error. The intention of the brackets was to get the last element overall instead the last element of the first EstimatedArrival. Consider this example:
            xmlDocument.LoadXml(
"<root>" +
"   <element>" +
"      <child>abc</child>" +
"   </element>" +
"   <element>" +
"      <child>xyz</child>" +
"   </element>" +
"</root>");
            Console.WriteLine(xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/root/element/child[last()]"));
            Console.WriteLine(xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("(/root/element/child)[last()]"));
the first will output "abc" while the second "xyz"